# How do I use the DOM to modify this?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I modify the style of the li element using DOM?

```
   <div id="tabbed-boosts">
     <ul>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

getElementById('tabbed-boosts').childNodes will get me to the UL, how do I modify the LI?

Also needs to work in IE6...

Comment: I would use CSS: `#tabbed-boosts li { .... }`

Comment: For DOM stuff, barring a good reason not to, I'd use a library to iron out the kinks and make things a **lot** more convenient. Some links: [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [more on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). With jQuery, for instance, it would be `$('#tabbed-boosts > ul > li').css(/* ... style stuff here*/)`. Other libs will be similarly easy.

Comment: Modify it *in what way*? @Sime: while my preferred technique, that's not necessarily (and certainly not *directly*) using the DOM...

Comment: @Shog9: Hence his not *answering* the question with it. :-)

Comment: modifying the class name specifically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lis = document.getElementById( 'tabbed-boosts' ).getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
for ( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ )
{
    lis[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.round( Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF ).toString( 16 );
}
```

Comment: That will go multiple levels deep, so if it's a nested list, it will have an adverse effect by processing `li` s it should leave alone. Given the structure, just `document.getElementById('tabbed-boosts').firstChild.childNodes` will do it provided there are no text nodes from whitespace.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I believe it's always okay to abstract a solution the way you need it. I usually wouldn't want to edit some lis, if I don't already know how the DOM structure looks like, so I can safely assume that the way to select the lis is good enough. And after all it's just an example.

Comment: I actually lied and it was an A element that I needed but this ended up working: document.getElementById('tabbed-boosts').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className="tab"

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using document.getElementById( 'tabbed-boosts' ).getElementsByTagName( 'li' ) will show up if you start using nested lists.  Using childNodes property will give you access to the direct children of that particular ul element.  For example

```
<ul id='tabbed-boosts'>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>
       <ul>
          <li> ... </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>... </li>
</ul>
```

using getElementsByTag will return ALL the 'li' elements within tabbed-boosts sub-tree, where childNodes will only return the first level 'li' elements.  In the example above you'd receive a collection of 4 elements using getElementById, including the nested LI whereas you would only receive a collection of 3 li elements using myUl.childNodes (shown below)

```
var myUl = document.getElementById('tabbed-boosts');

var myLi = myUl.childNodes;

for(var i = 0; i<myLi.length; i++)
{
   myLi[i].style....;

   // do whatever you want to the li items;
}
```